# How to align text to the top of a tabular cell?

Tags: tables, tabularx, itemize

So far I have

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist{topsep=0em,nosep}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r|X}
test text 1 & \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
              test text 2
              \begin{itemize}
              \item test item 1
              \item test item 2
              \end{itemize}
              \end{minipage}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

This produces something that looks like
[image]

however, what I want is for "test text 1" to be inline with "test text 2". How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You don't need a minipage in an `X` column!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this alignment is to set the *anchor* point for the `minipage` at the `[t]`op:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist{topsep=0em,nosep}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r|X}
test text 1 & \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
              test text 2
              \begin{itemize}
                \item test item 1
                \item test item 2
              \end{itemize}
              \end{minipage}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautifully simple, and intuitive! Thanks!